# Haskell libraries fail to build or have issues

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

Abstract question, sorry. Now finished most popular Haskell books and trying out libraries. Very many provide me with challenges in build problems with dependencies, deprecation and what not. Example:

```
Main.hs:5:1: warning: [-Wdeprecations]
    Module ‘Data.Attoparsec.Char8’ is deprecated:
      This module will be removed in the next major release.
  |
5 | import Data.Attoparsec.Char8
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Ok, one module loaded.
```

Trying to use `Spock` one of the dependencies was imported with the wrong name (camelcase). `Blaze` could not find all dependencies and so on. 
Is it common among real Haskellers (consider myself in Haskell kindergarten) to tackle these issues themselves, or am I just not getting the big picture in building it all wrong. Note I have most issues with Stack, less with Cabal and even less with a global install and GHCI (except for anything Gtk+ related).

Comment: Are you using a stack "LTS" resolver?

Comment: Sometimes, but not all the time. Would that make a world of difference? Haskell remains very complex IMO compared to eg. C++, Swift, Ruby etc.

Comment: Well, Stack LTS snapshots are guaranteed to use a compatible set of package-versions (that has already been tested to work together). — I prefer Cabal, and yes, I occasionally fix issues in other people's packages and send them a pull request. But for the most part, everything actually works out of the box. — Eh, now... what exactly is your question? As it stands, this seems both _too broad_ and _opinion-based_.

Comment: One way to improve your question would be to list the exact commands you're using to install your dependencies, as that would give answers a chance to suggest specific improvements.

Comment: We might close this one since it is too broad I realize. Would say I need more experience with Stack or Cabal.